# apache Redirect command without protocol

Tags: apache-2.4

I am new to Apache and it's syntactic elements, so i have to ask this here.
I wanted to know, if there is a way to use the command
`Redirect permanent / http://foo.bar` without specifying the protocol.
I have a ton of such statements on the VirtualHost-Layer and wish to preserver the used protocol.

Can i just leave it out?
Do i have to use RewriteCond? Is it applicable in the VirtualHost context?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: Took me 3 seconds to find an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372594/preserve-http-https-protocol-in-htaccess-redirects

Comment: @Alex That would be an answer, if i had asked for ```RewriteCond```, which i do not know, that it works in that context, hence the other text i wrote there.

Comment: @scones by "without specifying the protocol" you mean permanent redirect for both `http` and `https`?

Comment: @DavidB. yes. Sorry for the inexact terminology. I am trying to figure this whole area out.

Comment: In that case the link posted by @Alex is indeed what you should look into.